# systemd: Requires vs BindsTo?

Tags: systemd

I have two services running on the same machine, A and B. A is server, B is client

- A can running alone, but B must have A running before it can start
- if A crashes, stops, or restarts, B must stop or restart
- if B crashes, stops, or restarts, A is unaffected and can keep running

In B.service should I use `Requires` or `BindsTo` ?

```
[Unit]
Description=service B
After=A.service
Requires=A.service
```

or

```
[Unit]
Description=service B
After=A.service
BindsTo=A.service
```

Do I need to add the counter parts, i.e. `RequiredBy` or `ConsistsOf` in A.service ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using second option (BindsTo + After) suites your use case best. BindsTo allows B to stop when A stops, B starts when A starts. B does not start when A is not yet started.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what are the benefits?

Answer (score 3):

`BindsTo` differs from `Requires`. When `a.service` accidentally/abnormally stopped, `b.service` only stopped when using `BindsTo`.

The man page does say, with `Requires`, “explicitly” stopping `a.service` also stops `b.service`. But it’s unclear on the man page what about the same situation but using `BindsTo`. It also says accidentally stopping `a.service` also stops `b.service` in the section of `BindsTo`. But, again, it is not clear enough about what effect this accidentally stopping has when using `Requires`.

Please check this detailed article that explains things quite well.

https://pychao.com/2021/02/24/difference-between-partof-and-bindsto-in-a-systemd-unit/

*Disclosure: I'm not the author.*

Comment: +1 for the link